# Outbound TLS ciphers supported by Azure API Management Proxy

Tags: azure, tls1.2, azure-api-management

How to determine which TLS cipher suites are supported by Azure API Management?  These **do not appear to be documented anywhere clearly** and for CLIENT side (back end for outbound) - the only options in Azure are "HTTP/1.x" ON/Off and "HTTP/2" ON/OFF.  Many 3rd party apis are now locking down TLS cipher suites due to various weaknesses in TLS 1.2 implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring an Azure API Management endpoint to proxy to https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check , we see the following ciphers as of 4/3/2020:

```
{
               "given_cipher_suites": [
                              "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384", 
                              "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", 
                              "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
               ],
               "ephemeral_keys_supported": true,
               "session_ticket_supported": true,
               "tls_compression_supported": false,
               "unknown_cipher_suite_supported": false,
               "beast_vuln": false,
               "able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting": false,
               "insecure_cipher_suites": {},
               "tls_version": "TLS 1.2",
               "rating": "Probably Okay"
}
```